# How do i input a date as int with datetime.datetime()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass user input to a DB query as a datetime object and thought this might work but I get an error:

```
    start_date = "2022-07-29" #this is the user input
    start = datetime.datetime(start_date)
```

Do I really have to split the string etc. to make it work?

Comment: I don't get it. Following the second line, your `start_date` is a `datetime.datetime`. So what is `datetime.datetime(start_date)` supposed to do?

Comment: Now that you say it that doesn´t make sense yeah... anyway the underlying problem is that I don´t know how to pass the input other than using ´split´ on the string

Comment: That's a string, not an int. Shouldn't you be asking how to parse that string into a `date` or `datetime` ? Have you tried using `datetime.strptime` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/convert-string-jun-1-2005-133pm-into-datetime)

Comment: This is an XY question. You don't want to put in a string as an integer, you want to parse the date from a string.

Comment: it actually asks me for an int

Comment: Which means you're using the wrong method. Use `datetime.strptime` to Parse a STRing into a dateTIME

Comment: At least if you close for any reason, close for the reason that it's a duplicate of the one @PanagiotisKanavos linked.

Comment: @shadowtalker there were multiple close reasons. When I added the duplicate there was already an `unclear` vote. I suspect if the third vote was also `unclear` (which it is), that got picked as the single close reason

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start_date = "2022-07-29"                                       
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d") 
>>> str(dt)
'2022-07-29 00:00:00'
```